# In Laravel limiting the rate of jobs being processed without limiting how many jobs can be added

Tags: laravel, queue, jobs

Basically I need the following, I have queue in Laravel that need to process jobs to a given time rate (ex. Just one jobs every x amount of seconds, because it is an API request). But the user can insert any amount of jobs he want into the queue.

[image]

Comment: I would say that are many ways to sort this out. If the order they get called doesn't have to to always the same they got in the queue.. I would just go for: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queues#rate-limiting. Otherwise I would implement a custom solution to manually dispatch 3 jobs every X seconds, reading from a table or similar.